# Using SQL function in query and handling exception

Tags: sql, function, clr, .net-assembly

In a query I am using an SQL function (which calls a .NET function for xml transformation)

```
SELECT ApplyXMLTransform((subquery which returns XML type), (subquery which gets the XSLT) FROM SomeTable
```

when the function ApplyXMLTransform encounters an exception the whole query blows up ... is there a way to prevent exception from destroying the whole recordset (query wise, I realize I could modify the function to handle exception in the managed code)?

The exception itself is a mystory too because when I query the record that is the culprit I see no invalid charecters etc that would constitue the exception ... but that is another can of worm ... here is the error:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "ApplyXsltTransform": 
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 21, position 417.
System.Xml.XmlException: 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml.CreateMemoryStreamFromXmlReader(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml..ctor(XmlReader value)
   at NF.Sql.Extensions.XSLTTransform.Transform(SqlXml inputDataXML, SqlXml inputTransformXML)
.
```

Comment: catch the exception in the function and instead return a nice little string 'Error Occurred' or something.

Comment: Thank you, that is eactly what I am doing and returning the exception details. I guess there really is no way to handle it through the query ...